# Dictionary to pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
{'1': -1.4, '8': -6.04, '6': 0.75}
```

I want to convert this to a dataframe that looks like:

```
     code  score 
      1     -1.4 
      8     -6.04
      6     0.75
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(data=list(d.items()), columns=["code", "score"])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Dataframe()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/frame.html), as follows:

```
d = {'1': -1.4, '8': -6.04, '6': 0.75}
df = pd.DataFrame({'code': d.keys(), 'score': d.values()})
```

or use [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) + [`.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
d = {'1': -1.4, '8': -6.04, '6': 0.75}
df = pd.Series(d).rename_axis(index='code').reset_index(name='score')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

  code  score
0    1  -1.40
1    8  -6.04
2    6   0.75
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
d = {'1': -1.4, '8': -6.04, '6': 0.75}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index', columns=['score']) \
                 .rename_axis('code') \
                 .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  code  score
0    1  -1.40
1    8  -6.04
2    6   0.75
```

Answer (score 0):

The generic code to convert JSON to any number of columns dataframe

```py
data={'1': -1.4, '8': -6.04, '6': 0.75}
df=pd.DataFrame([data]).T.reset_index() # create dataframe and transpose it
df.columns=['code', 'score'] # set the column names
```

Result:

```
  code  score
0    1  -1.40
1    8  -6.04
2    6   0.75
```